# Robot framework run on Github actions can't get test return codes

Tags: automated-tests, github-actions, robotframework

I am using Github actions to run my test with robot framework, when test complete, and in bash shell I can get return code in special variable via `$?`, but even test fail it also get 0

```
name: Test
on: [workflow_dispatch]

jobs:
  TEST-Run:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    - name: install
      run: |
        pip3 install -r requirements.txt

    - name: Run Tests
      run: |
        robot test.robot

    - name: Set Robot Return Code
      run: |
        echo "ROBOT_RC=$?" >> "$GITHUB_ENV"

    - name: If Auto Test Pass Rate Not 100%, Job Will Fail
      if: env.ROBOT_RC != '0'
      run: |
        echo "Auto Test Pass Rate Not 100%, Please Check Test Result"
        exit 1
```

Any help or explanation is welcome! Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [`jobs.<job_id>.steps[*].run`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idstepsrun):

> Each `run` keyword represents a new process and shell in the runner environment. When you provide multi-line commands, each line runs in the same shell.

So, you need to combine those steps in one:

```yaml
    - name: Run Tests
      run: |
        robot test.robot
        echo "ROBOT_RC=$?" >> "$GITHUB_ENV"
```

or,

```yaml
    - name: Run Tests
      run: |
        robot test.robot; ROBOT_RC=$?
        echo "ROBOT_RC=$ROBOT_RC" >> "$GITHUB_ENV"
```

See [`jobs.<job_id>.steps[*].shell`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idstepsshell) for more details.